# How to Get the images from cached image file into drawable

Tags: android, image, caching, drawable

I load images from an URL and save as cache file. Now I want to get the cached images into a drawable. How can I do this?
I load the images from url by using this ImageLoader class

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
Handler handler=new Handler();//handler to display images in UI thread
Bitmap bitmap;
public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
   bitmap  =memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
        stream1.close();

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70000;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

The following is the method I created in main Activity

```
private String[] mStrings = {
            "my url image1.jpg"
            "my url image2.jpg"
            "my url image3.jpg"



    };
    ImageLoader imgldr;
    private Bitmap loadBitmap(int width, int height, int index) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        b.eraseColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
        int padding = getBaseContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                R.dimen.padding_large);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        /**In the below line i need to get the cahe file as drawable**/
        /**im getting error in this line**/
        Drawable d = imgldr.DisplayImage(mStrings[index], imageView);

        int margin = 7;
        int border = 3;
        Rect r = new Rect(margin, margin, width - margin, height - margin);

        int imageWidth = r.width() - (border * 2);
        int imageHeight = imageWidth * d.getIntrinsicHeight()
                / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
        if (imageHeight > r.height() - (border * 2)) {
            imageHeight = r.height() - (border * 2);
            imageWidth = imageHeight * d.getIntrinsicWidth()
                    / d.getIntrinsicHeight();
        }

        r.left += ((r.width() - imageWidth) / 2) - border;
        r.right = r.left + imageWidth + border + border;
        r.top += ((r.height() - imageHeight) / 2) - border;
        r.bottom = r.top + imageHeight + border + border;

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(0xFFC0C0C0);
        c.drawRect(r, p);
        r.left += border;
        r.right -= border;
        r.top += border;
        r.bottom -= border;

        d.setBounds(r);
        d.draw(c);

        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use serious libraries instead of your custom implementations. The great library for downloading and caching images is [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)